# How to query multiple fields in the db?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code which has two fields that are queried.

How can I do `LIKE` with 3-5 fields?

Code:

```
 mysql_query("SELECT * FROM practice_exams where 
 person_id = '$pid' and message_exam LIKE 
 '%$q%' OR message_note LIKE '%$q%'");
```

Comment: what do fields are you referring to? do you mean limiting the number of rows returned for limiting the fields that are SELECTED (not using a wildcard like *)?

Comment: What do you mean by "querying fields"? That they are in the `where` clause? If so you already reference 3 (though should probably have brackets in there)

Comment: Could you rephrase the question so that it makes sense, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you mean searching instead of querying. Adding more fields becomes easier if you structure your statement nicer:

```
mysql_query("
     SELECT * FROM practice_exams
     WHERE person_id = '$pid'
       AND (
            message_exam LIKE '%$q%'
            OR message_note LIKE '%$q%' 
            OR other_note LIKE '%$q%'
            OR other_things LIKE '%$q%'
           )
");
```

I've added some parens there, as I assume that's what your query actually should do.

Note that a lot of `LIKE` statements do not benefit the query speed.